# Waistcoats and Tzitzit

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1722/4504) notes that the Chayei Adam knew of (and approved of) French Jews who would wear tzitziot on their waistcoats. However, [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waistcoat#History) of the Wikipedia article shows that the waistcoats worn in the Chayei Adam's days were significantly different in their form than our modern ones.

Here are images of the waistcoats of the Chayei Adam's period:

[image: 18th Century Waistcoat]

And the modern era:

[image: 20-21st Century Waistcoat]

Please note that these garments would still need to be split most of the way up the back to have 4 corners, AFAIK.

Are our modern waistcoats chayav (or at least accepting of) tzitzit?

Comment: I only see two corners on the modern waistcoat you show.

Comment: @DoubleAA, there should be two in the back. I doubt that it would really be chayav if there were 4 kanfot all in front. However in any case, I couldn't find any photos of the older design from the back when I did a quick search, so I didn't look for ones from the from either.

Comment: So you have a garment that you cut up the back to make four corners. Why might it be exempt from Tzitzit?

Comment: @DoubleAA, because it's not intended to be chayav, according to some of the opinions which R' Hirsch brings in his notes on the maftir of Shelach. Furthermore, the question still remains as to whether they are chayav, even if they theoretically have four corners.

Comment: "because it's not intended to be chayav, according to some of the opinions which R' Hirsch brings in his notes on the maftir of Shelach." Please always include your motivation in the question not in comments and not only when prompted to include it. "Furthermore, the question still remains as to whether they are chayav, even if they theoretically have four corners." To me that reads like "can I wear polka dotted socks in a Sukkah while eating gefilta fish?" If you have no reason to think it is a problem, then why should anyone care?

Comment: 4 corners in front was the Machlokes between beis yosef and Ramma end of siman 10. See Mishna Berurah #36. The chayei adam is klal 10 siff 9.

Comment: Also, the basic shiur for tzitzis is ignored in your question. Is it big enough for a nine year old to cover most of his body and would an adult be willing to go out his front door wearing just this? That is the shiur.

Comment: @user6591, would anyone actually be willing to go out wearing just a tallit katan? I for one wouldn't and mine  isn't even the minimum shire! (nor is it huge, it's about average)