# I sleep with tzitzis on. Is there any part of the body they shouldn't touch?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, sleep, tallit-katan

I sleep with my tzitzis on. Is there any part of the body the tzitzis should not touch?

Comment: Why would you think there are any limitations on what they can touch? It's one thing when you wear tzitzis by day - there are indeed different opinions and customs (this was once discussed here on m.y) about whether they can be worn directly on the skin; but at night it can't really be helped.

Comment: @alex if you dont wear pants while sleeping, then they can touch your thighs. my understanding was that the tzitzis can only touch those parts of the body that are not usually covered

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case. Consider when people wear their tzitzis tucked into their waistband (some do this always, but even those who usually wear them sticking out, have to tuck them in when they're visiting a cemetery); don't they inevitably touch one's legs then?

Comment: @alex yes they may touch it but that doesnt make it right

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1703

Answer (score 8):

This is sort of an argument from absence, but...

Shulchan Aruch ([Orach Chaim 8:16](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40431&st=&pgnum=25)) describes a case where a person sleeps at night wearing his tallis, as to whether he has to recite a berachah on it the next morning. If there were indeed any problem with what parts of the body the tzitzis strings touch, then I would think this would be a logical place for one or more of the commentaries to point it out. Since I haven't found any that do so, I would assume that this is not an issue. (Unless someone else can find sources that talk about this explicitly.)

Comment: לא ראינו אינו ראיה